# Redirect from http to https does not work (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect all requests to my website from non-www to www AND from http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now, I can still open http://www.my-domain.de without it redirecting me to https://...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That is only to be expected, because `http://www.my-domain.de` does not fulfill _both_ of your conditions - which are joined by an implicit AND. You need to use the `[OR]` flag to change this behavior.

Comment: When using [OR] I get a "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error when opening the page in Chrome.

Comment: And for what address? Guessing you probably doubled the `www.` part now? Maybe don’t try and make the host name in the substitution dynamic, if there is no necessity for that, but just hard-code it.